# Codeigniter : You did not select a file to uplaod

Tags: php, codeigniter

following is the code that i am trying to upload file . and the error i get is

```
You did not select a file to upload.
```

Please help me with this how can i fix this

```
<?php echo form_open_multipart('garage/do_upload');?>

<input type="file" name="userfile"   />

<input type="submit" value="upload" />

</form>
```

**do_upload function**

```
   public function  do_upload() { 

    $this->load->library('upload');

    $files = $_FILES;
    $cpt = count($_FILES['userfile']['name']);
    for($i=0; $i<$cpt; $i++)
    {           
        $_FILES['userfile']['name']= $files['userfile']['name'][$i];
        $_FILES['userfile']['type']= $files['userfile']['type'][$i];
        $_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name']= $files['userfile']['tmp_name'][$i];
        $_FILES['userfile']['error']= $files['userfile']['error'][$i];
        $_FILES['userfile']['size']= $files['userfile']['size'][$i];    

        $this->upload->initialize($this->set_upload_options());
        if($this->upload->do_upload()){
            echo 'Done'; 
            die; 
        }
        else {
            print_r($this->upload->display_errors());
        }
    }



}


     private function set_upload_options()
    {   
        //upload an image options
        $config = array();
        $config['upload_path'] = './uploads/';
        $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png';
        $config['max_size']      = '10000000000000';
        $config['overwrite']     = FALSE;

        return $config;
    }
```

i will use this code for multiple image uploads but curretly its not workign for single image , Kindly help

Comment: Make this change to input. name="userfile[]"

Comment: Your missing the name in here `$this->upload->do_upload('userfile')` http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/file_uploading.html#the-controller

Answer (score 0):

```
public function do_upload()
{
    $error = NULL;
    // check permission of upload_path
    // I recommended that user fullpath
    $this->load->library('upload', array(
        'delete_origin'     => TRUE,
        'upload_path'       => './uploads/',
        'remove_spaces'     => TRUE,
        'file_ext_tolower'  => TRUE,
        'allowed_types'     => 'jpg|png|jpeg',
        'max_size'          => '4096', // 1024 KB  => 1 MB
        'max_width'         => '1920',
        'max_height'        => '1080',
    ));

    if( ! $this->upload->do_upload('userfile') )
    {
        $error = $this->upload->display_errors();
    }
    else
    {
        $data = $this->upload->data();
    }

    return ( empty( $error ) ) ? $data : $error;
}
```